# A loop to iterate a folder to show items

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I have a folder and I want to write a script to show all the items inside.
I know the loop is like:

```
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,200) DO (
  ECHO %%A
)
```

but how do I iterate a folder using the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for %%a in (your_dir/*) do (
//somethin you want
)
```

Comment: It should be a back slash not a forward slash, and it should be doublequoted for safety, i.e. `@For %%# In ("Your_Dir\*")Do @Echo(%%#`. Technically however, that doesn't show all files either. To do that I would recommend `@For /F "Delims=" %%# In ('Dir /B/S/A-D "Your_Dir" 2^>NUL')Do @Echo(%%#`.